# Gstreamer: How to mux h264 stream into mp4 and use it in real time?

Tags: html5-video, gstreamer, h.264

I am using gstreamer to leverage hardware encoding on my app. The end goal is to be able to play the stream natively in an html `<video>` tag. I believe I need to put the encoded h264 stream into an mp4 container to achieve this. The end of the pipeline should be an `appsink` pad that my python code can pull from to serve the video to the webpage.

My current pipeline is looks like this:

```
videotestsrc ! nvvidconv ! omxh264enc control-rate=2 bitrate=4000000 ! video/x-h264 ! mp4mux ! appsink name=camera_stream
```

Running this with `gst-launch-1.0` gives this error:

```
===== NVMEDIA: NVENC =====
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 4 
H264: Profile = 66, Level = 40 
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMP4Mux:mp4mux0: Downstream is not seekable - will not be able to create a playable file
Additional debug info:
gstqtmux.c(2780): gst_qt_mux_start_file (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMP4Mux:mp4mux0
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
```

I tried a modified version of this pipeline as a sanity check:

```
videotestsrc ! nvvidconv ! omxh264enc control-rate=2 bitrate=4000000 ! video/x-h264 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

This was successful with `gst-launch-1.0 -e`, where the `-e` flag gives the end-of-signal to the stream. Once I end the pipeline, there is a playable file. However, I want to be able to access this data while the pipeline is still running.

###### Question: How can I pipe this stream into an mp4 container such that my app can access the processed data in real time via appsink?

EDIT: Converting to fragmented MP4 allows the pipeline to run successfully with appsink:

```
videotestsrc ! omxh264enc control-rate=2 bitrate=4000000 ! video/x-h264 ! mp4mux fragment-duration=10 ! appsink name=camera_sink
```

There is one problem and one preference issue with this updated version:

- Problem: The stream crashes if I refresh the webpage.
- Preference: The stream has 4-5s of latency, which is too much for my project. This may just be a limitation of the chunked MP4 method as I saw a similar latency using `hlssink` previously.

Comment: is your appsink code running? I think it may need to be ready to consume the stream in order for the pipeline to start properly.

Comment: Hi ! 

Why not using WebRTCBin ( which can handle H264 ) or hlssink to send to a <video> tags. Depending on latency you need theses Gstreamer elements are more appropriates to do that.

Comment: @2wheat3rock MP4 is not a streaming (it is progressive) download format. You want to output **fragmented MP4** and play via MediaSource Extensions API (it allows you to feed data to the video player whenever you need to). Also MSE does not work on Safari browser so for that one you need to output as HLS (putting your H264 inside a TS not MP4 container)... I would first try outputting HLS and see if a player like [videoJS can play your stream](https://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/) link. If yes, then that HLS link should work on all browsers.

Comment: @2wheat3rock If you are trying to stream to a browser, I would suggest using HLS as it is file based with a little bit of latency. You can use gstreamers `hlssink2` element. This will generate a manifest `.m3u8` file that will have to be accessed from a browser. You can use `hlsjs` player or videoJS or any other player of your choice in the browser to stream and play the HLS stream you generated from gstreamer. There will be a 10+ second latency depending on the length of the segment you choose.

Comment: @VC.One @GuruGovindan I have tried using HLS in the past using `hlssink`. It provided a stable stream, but the latency was too great for my purposes. I was getting 4-5s at least, and I'm trying to keep my stream < 0.5-1s.  @VC.One your suggestion of using fmp4 did help with python consuming this stream! However, the latency was similar to HLS and the app crashed when I refreshed the page. I am planning to spend the next few days looking at WebRTCBin as per @Ludovic Bouguerra 's suggestion

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for latency < 1s? I have posted a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75910947/decode-h264-video-in-mediasource-sourcebuffer-from-gstreamer There are many similar questions on SO but none offers a solution with an acceptable latency.