# Decode h264 video in MediaSource sourcebuffer from Gstreamer

Tags: javascript, gstreamer, h.264, media-source

I generate a h264 baseline profile level 2 video via the gstreamer pipeline:

```
... ! videoenc ! queue ! h264parse ! appsink caps=video/x-h264,alignment=(string)au
```

I receive the stream in an html page where I do:

```
this.mediaSource = new MediaSource();
console.log(MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.424014"'));//True
const vv = document.getElementById("mytryplayer") as HTMLVideoElement;
vv.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.mediaSource);
this.mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', (_) => {
        this.sourceBuffer = this.mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.424014"');
        this.sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updatestart', function(e) { console.log('updatestart: ' + e); });
        this.sourceBuffer.addEventListener('error', function(e) { console.log('error: ' + e); });
});
```

and I feed with:

```
this.sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(received_stream_from_app_sink);
```

The Gstreamer app_sink sends data and it's properly received in 'received_stream_from_app_sink' in the HTML page. I can decode the same stream in Android so I know that both the transmission and the original video stream are correct.

After the second packet, I receive the error callback and the source buffer is being closed.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That's rather incomplete code you posted.. and what is even the actual error?

Comment: Are you wrapping your video in ISOBMFF somewhere along the way?  As far as I know, you won't be able to send raw H.264 to the MediaSource.

Comment: @Brad, thank you. Are you suggesting to add some kind of mp4mux plugin in the Gstreamer pipeline? What kind of wrapper do I need in order to import to MediaSource?

Comment: @Brad, I see some of your comments on other similar questions. Are you aware of a Github example of h264 -> Gstreamer -> websocket server -> -> -> html -> websocket client -> MediaSource ?

Comment: Interesting similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75075539/gstreamer-how-to-mux-h264-stream-into-mp4-and-use-it-in-real-time but no answer with low latency.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what the exact graph is to mux into MP4 in a way that'll work, but you do need the container there.  Also, no need for Web Sockets... or MediaSource for that matter... you could simply load a URL in the `<video>` element and have it stream the output from Gstreamer.  For what it's worth, last time I did this I used WebM with VP8 or VP9.  Webcam -> FFmpeg (as a child process to...) -> Node.js (sending data over HTTP to...) -> Browser Client's Video Element.  Glass to glass latency, just a couple hundred milliseconds with no optimization.

Comment: @Brad, My challenge is that I have no network connectivity between the gstreamer sender and the html page. I have a totally different connection protocol which has nothing to do with Ethernet. I can't do rtsp on gstreamer and <video src=https://....> My connectivity protocol can just ensure that binary packets sent from server are received in javascript.

Comment: Another idea is to use jmuxer and if I plug this technology, the first packet is decoded and the first frame appears on video element but it stucks after that - I don't know why. jmuxer is a great technology but it's not actively supported at this time. I can't find a good WORKING example of jmuxer.

Comment: @gregoiregentil How are you getting your data to the browser if there's no connectivity?  Where is your Web Socket connection?  No matter what, you could always do a Service Worker to get your data to the video element, but in any case you (MediaSource or otherwise) you still need that container.  The problem with MP4 is the MOOV atom and its position.  You can work around this with fragmenting.  Or, use WebM and it "just works".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252931/discussion-between-gregoiregentil-and-brad).

Comment: @gregoiregentil _"Using [jMuxer](https://github.com/samirkumardas/jmuxer)... the first packet is decoded and the first frame appears on video element but it's stuck after that"_ The fastest way to get an Answer is to **share something testable** in an HTML5 player. Is there any way to output (from GStreamer) a few seconds of video for testing? Your question should be simply _"Given these bytes (show a download link) how can I play them in the browser? I have tried using jMuxer like this (and show jMuxer testable code to load same shared bytes)"_. Someone will help fix that stuck frame issue.

Comment: @VC.One Yes, this is what I did, I dumped a sample and analyzed the problem on my full stack PC. To close those comments, jmuxer can work in this situation and mux raw H264 to be fed into MediaSource. Thank you.